# Chunking in Azure Logic Apps SFTP-SSH Create action doesn't work

Tags: sftp, azure-logic-apps

What I want to achieve:

1. Send a >50MB file via HTTP to a Logic App
2. The Logic App to save the file to an SFTP server

An error I am getting in the SFTP-SSH 'Create file' action:

> The provided file size '64065320' for the create or update operation
> exceeded the maximum allowed file size '52428800' using non-chunked
> transfer mode. Please enable chunked transfer mode to create or update
> large files.

Chunking on the SFTP-SSH 'Create file' action is enabled. [Overriding chunk size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/connectors/connectors-sftp-ssh#override-chunk-size) doesn't help. [Using the body of the 'Compose' action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#chunked-message-handling-for-connectors) as an input for 'Create file' also doesn't help.

The current workflow:

[image: Workflow]

SFTP-SSH 'Create file' action parameters:

[image: 'Create file' action parameters]

SFTP-SSH 'Create file' action settings:

[image: 'Create file' action settings]

Error:

[image: Error]

Any ideas about the reason of the error?

**P.S.** I want to clarify the issue; it is about a very specific workflow: when a large file is sent to a Logic App via HTTP (the 'When a HTTP request is received' trigger) it needs to be saved to an SFTP server. Not transformed, just saved as it is. I know that when collecting (pulling) a large file from elsewhere (SFTP/blob/etc.) and saving it to SFTP, chunking works fine. But in this scenario (pushing the file to the Logic App) it doesn't. Although the [Handle large messages with chunking in Azure Logic Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#chunked-message-handling-for-connectors) article at first says that "*Logic App triggers don't support chunking*" and "*for actions that support and are enabled for chunking you can't use trigger bodies*", then it gives a workaround: "*Instead, use the Compose action. Specifically, you must create a body field by using the Compose action to store the data output from the trigger body. Then, to reference the data, in the chunking action, use @body('Compose')*". Well, this workaround didn't work for me as seen from the screenshots I provided. I'd appreciate if someone could clarify how to overcome this issue.

Comment: Set up the chunking Over HTTP Action.

Comment: @MadhurajVadde-MT, there's no HTTP action in this Logic App - there's only HTTP trigger where chunking can't be configured.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-handle-large-messages#chunked-message-handling-for-logic-apps), the endpoint to which you are sending the request,  use chunking to download the whole data by sending partial data which enable HTTP connector. To comply with this connector's limit, Logic Apps splits any message larger than 30 MB into smaller chunks. You can split up large content downloads and uploads over HTTP so that your logic app and an endpoint can exchange large messages.

You can even refer [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/62753/azure-logic-apps-large-file-handling.html) which discusses the same topic.

Comment: The Documentation link is the same that I mentioned in my question. I followed its guidelines: "you can't use trigger bodies... Instead, use the Compose action" - it didn't help. When a large file is sent to the Logic App via HTTP trigger, I use the Compose action to store the trigger body, but I am not able to save the Compose action body to SFTP server anyway even though 'Allow chunking' is enabled (see screenshot). As to the second link you provided - I don't need to apply any mapping to the large file, I just need to save it. So I shouldn't need an Azure Function for this.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps,

discussion [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-integration-services-blog/the-provided-file-size-xxxxxxxxx-for-the-create-or-update/ba-p/1992139) handles the problem. In the logic app code, in the compose section change `"inputs":"@variables()"` to `"inputs":{"body":"@variables()"}` and in the sftp section `"body": "@inputs('Compose')"` to `"body": "@body('Compose')"`